# Relate two tables with a third

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I need to create the `insert` for the table Localitzada in order to relate Apartment and Street. I have already imported the data from a huge csv file.

Each apartment must be in one street already defined in an Import table with `listing_url, apartment_name, apartment_description, street_name and neighbourhood`

[image]

Comment: Provide some test data and if possible the expected result.

Comment: Please review [ask] in the help section. Following that as  a template for your question greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer.   Part of your problem here is your data model is flawed. Your model creates a many-to-many relationship between Apartment and Street. But your requirement states "apartment must be in one street" which defines a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you corretly, you can looking for the `insert into ... select ... from ... join` syntax, like so:

```
insert into import
    (id_neighbourhood, zipcode, apartment_name, description, street_name)
select
    s.id_neighbourhood,
    l.zip_code,
    a.name,
    a.description,
    s.name
from localitzada l
inner join appartment a on a.id_apartment = l.id_apartment
inner join street s on s.id_street = l.id_street
```

Comment: I wanted to insert into localitzada, the import table is the one I use to copy data from the csv. But making some changes your answer works well. Thanks